# Maximum wattage of a fat cell

Tags: nutrition, burn-fat

How fast can fat be burned?
I am not asking about how quickly weight can be lost but how much of a human's calorific need can be met by fat alone? Is it healthy to work at the maximum power output of fat for sustained periods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although it changes from person to person (weight), approximately 60-85% of maximal heart rate are accepted as fat burning zone. If you keep your intensity (lower is better) between above mentioned intervals, up to 70% of the calories burned can come from fat . This article may somewhat help you. [Fat Burning During Exercise](http://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.3810/psm.1998.09.1143)

how fast? do the math :-)
every 45 minutes your run you lose 1 pound

Comment: That sounds very optimistic. Sorry. A kilogram of raw fat has 9300 kcal energy stored for the body. Therefore you  would have to burn 4200 kcal in 45 min of runing. I guess that means running around near the sound barrier

Comment: Yes you are right  :-) But in the answer I wrote;  you lose 1 pound, not 1 pound of fat. May be I should have been more clear about it. Thanks for the correction.

Comment: I should try. I sweat alot uring running. So I guess I can reach 1 Kilo per 45 minutes. But the weight loss will be 90-99% water then ( and a lot of pride when I realize how slow my running is)